# How do I disconnect users from a file stored on a NAS?

Tags: ssh, network-share, network-attached-storage, file-server, emc

We recently migrated our file servers from a Windows file server to an EMC VNXe NAS device.

Previously, when a user needed into a critical file that someone else had open and the situation warranted, I'd log into the file server and disconnect any unwanted users from the file.

How is this done in a NAS device such as mine?

UPDATE to clarify what I do and do not have:

The VNXe system has a web management interface that allows management of the disks, shares, users, access, pools, authentication, system status, updates, etc.

It does not have the ability to view file-level share contents.

There is also SSH on the device, but it's been a while since I used a Linux CLI and I don't know where to begin doing this particular task in a Linux CLI.

Comment: not familiar with the emc but it should have a web\cli interface that you need to use in order to login, so conceptually its the same as a windows based nas device you'll just be more then likely using a web interface.

Comment: There's no file management in the web interface. There is SSH access. It's been a long time since I was comfortable with Linux CLI though.

Comment: You have a NAS with no interface *except* SSH? The searches I see for EMC VNXe devices are nearly 10 grand...with no graphical interface for configuring your shares and such?

Comment: ouch, hmm time to brush up on your *nx skillz.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim, I didn't say it didn't have share management in the UI or that it only had SSH. It does have a web UI for management. And you can manage accounts, shares, disks, pools, etc there. What you cannot do is look at a file-level view and disconnect individual users from individual files.

Comment: ok looks like there is a windows instable called UIMCLI from emc that you may want to install.  Hopefully that will ldo what you want.

Comment: Checking out the CLI @tonyroth found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty much the same as with a Windows Server-based network storage system: In Computer Management Console connect to the VNXe NAS using the Connect To Another Computer option.

Most of the various Computer Management controls will not work, but under System Tools - Shared Folders, Shares, Sessions, and Open Files will work here just the same as using a Windows Server-based network storage drive. You can view open files, user sessions connected, and unlock files as necessary.

No WebUI, rusty *nix skills? No problem.

Comment: haha thats funny the answer was so obvious we missed it!

Comment: I just assumed that the console only worked for windows machines and can't even recall what prompted me to try using it against the VNXe. I'm certainly glad it ended up working the way it did.